# how can I get into my ubuntu server with my mobile?

Tags: xubuntu

I know how to see/login trought a computer, but how do I view them from my mobile. I have a samsung galaxy s3. Android.

Answer (score 1):

For login via SSH: [ConnectBot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.madgag.ssh.agent) or [JuiceSSH](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh)

For login via VNC: [android-vnc-viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=android.androidVNC)

Answer (score 0):

For desktop remote control
use "x11vnc" on your Ubuntu machine,
vnc viewer is available for mobile ( android, windows phone ). I use "tiny vnc" on my windows phone, it should be also available for android.

other than vnc, you can also use "splashtop"
for desktop sharing. (Splashtop is available for android).
you can download splashtop for ubuntu from link http://www.splashtop.com/linux

if you want to control your desktop through internet connection, "teamviewer" is the best.
( teamviewer is available for android )

apart from these if you want to share files only,
install "vsftpd" on your Ubuntu machine.
and connect through file manager ( ftp option is available on some file manager eg. FILE MANAGER by Rythm Software) on your android phone.